# In TDengine, can 2.2 td client connect to 2.4 td server ? taos connect failed, reason: Invalid app version

Tags: tdengine

2.2 td client can't connect 2.4 td server.

[1;36m2022-01-11 09:49:43.175135 dnode:1 is running with nohup /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/debug/build/bin/taosd -c /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/sim/dnode1/cfg > /dev/null 2>&1 & [0m
[1;36m2022-01-11 09:49:43.693252 the dnode:1 has been started.[0m
2022-01-11 09:49:43.693648 Procedures for testing self-deployment
taos connect failed, reason: Invalid app version.

Comment: What's the compatibility of TDengine?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use same version of taosc(client) & taosd(server).